# Adding Content to the Many to Many Field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am learning django and i am creating a simple Music Library which has 2 basic Models `Song` and `Singer`

Now a Singer has a `many-to-many` relationship with Song

**Modles.py**

```
class Singer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Singer', max_length=255)


class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lyrics = models.TextField()
    singer = models.ManyToManyField(Singer)
```

Now In my Admin Section i modified the singer (Multi Select) Field to Use the [Select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) Jquery Plugin and I added the **Tagging Support** for this Plugin Using the code below :

```
$(".js-example-tags").select2({
  tags: true
})
```

so i can type and add any new Singer's Name (who is not already Present) at the same time while adding the Song as i don't want a separate UI to add Singers Name.

Now I don't know how to proceed with adding this new Singer's Name to Singers Table and then relate him to the Specific Song in django-admin.

When i submit the form with any New Singer's Name, I get Validation Error. I have searched a lot but cannot seem to find any solution to this.

**UPDATE**

I tried to add a new Song from the Add Song Page in Admin Panel, In the Singer Field i specified "Some Singer" ( this singer is not present in my DB ). On submitting the form i get the error :

> "Some SInger" is not a valid value for a primary key.

**forms.py**

```
class SongForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Song
        fields = ['title', 'lyrics', 'image', 'singer', 'pub_date']
        widgets = {
            'singer': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'multipleSelectBox'}),
        }
```

**admin.py**

```
class SongAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        def __init__(self):
            pass

        css = {
            "all": ('css/plugins/select2.min.css', )
        }
        js = (
            'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js',
            'js/plugins/select2.min.js',
            'js/songs.js'
        )

    form = SongForm



admin.site.register(Song, SongAdmin)
```

Comment: Maybe if you post your Validation Error, it will be easier  :)

Comment: Updated the Question with the error.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to insert it as a primary key:) can you show the code which you are using after the upload, the python code (the forms.py if you are using a form or the view.py function)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Many to Many Field values if they don't exist in Django Admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33254216/how-to-add-many-to-many-field-values-if-they-dont-exist-in-django-admin)

Comment: updated the Question

Comment: Right Now i amnot doing anything after the Upload. The validaiton error is the default Functunality because i tried to add an option that does not exist in the Multiple Select Field to admin. Howver I would like this to be added when not in table.